# SharePoint Web Part Connections & Filters

Tags: filter

I have a basic web part page with a number of webparts which use one identifier to filter a long list of results.

The problem is there are about 25 records and it roams all the way down my page - is there anyways I can configure it so that it splits in to two columns or reads horizontally instead of vertically?

Thanks - Rob

Comment: Do you mean you have 25 webparts, placed vertically on the same page, or what?

Comment: Also, what version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: A screenshot (even with parts redacted) would help I think

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the Filter Web Part to apply the filter, you could connect this to a Data View Web Part rather than a List View Web Part.

You could then modify the XSLT such that it outputs each 13 items into new divs, which could then be floated to ensure that they appear in "columns" in the view that they are presented on.